# Application.OpenForms encapsulation

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to encapsulate this function in a static class?

```
private void btnAddWorker_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    bool isOpen = false;

    foreach (Form _f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (_f is frmAddWorker)
        {
            isOpen = true;
            _f.Focus();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isOpen == false)
    {
        frmAddWorker AddWorker = new frmAddWorker() { MdiParent = this };
        AddWorker.Show();
    }
}
```

something like that:

```
public class Forms(){public void openForm(form _f){...}}
```

I want to prevent write the original code in all forms buttons that open.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Focus<T>(Form parent) where T : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    bool isOpen = false;
    foreach (var f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f is T)
        {
            isOpen = true;
            (f as Form).Focus();
            break;    
        }
     }

     if (!isOpen)
     {
         T newForm = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
         newForm.MdiParent = parent;
         newForm.Show();
     }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
StaticClass.Focus<frmAddWorker>(this);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be wise to constrain `T` to be a form?

Comment: and `.First` won't work since it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Like I said "Not tested"